# React-Select V2 with react-tiny-virtual-list

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to implement integrate [react-select v2](https://deploy-preview-2289--react-select.netlify.com) with [react-tiny-virtual-list](https://github.com/clauderic/react-tiny-virtual-list)

I am successfully loading 10k items into the select component and it runs pretty good.

I created an example at:
https://codesandbox.io/s/qko9vw1yzw

I am replacing the Menu component with a custom virtualized one which loads items on demand, the problem is that i do not understand how i render the Option component with all it's passed props, in the example above the option items do not get the hover/focus event and do not have the onClick event handler I passed.

I went over the docs a couple of times and still unable to figure how to do it.